# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am getting this error when I use find 
html

```
<button  (click)="saveDialog(listitem)"></button>
```

when I click button dialog will open and I am passing listitem to dialog

DialogOverviewExampleDialog

```
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private http: HttpClient) {

  this.selectedElementSymbols = this.Results.find(e => e.name === this.data.listitem.name).symbols;

});

  }

}
```

Here I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined at  DialogOverviewExampleDialog

```
this.selectedElementSymbols = this.Results.find(e => e.name === this.data.listitem.name).symbols;
```

Comment: `get` is async.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the check inside **`subscribe`**, otherwise Results will be undefined since you are making an async call

```
this.http.get('https://myjson.com/qbot1')
    .subscribe((res:any) => {
        this.Results = res;
        if (data.listitem) {
            this.selectedElementSymbols = this.Results.find(e => e.name === this.data.listitem.name).symbols;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Or it could be that it was not a successful call, and perhaps another `subscribe` callback was called. (`.subscribe(success, failure, complete);`)

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: @itsme did the answer help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415350/cascading-dropdown-edit-is-not-working-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

It means your `this.Results` object is undefined. Put a null check before that statement.

```
if(this.Results)
this.selectedElementSymbols = this.Results.find(e => e.name === this.data.listitem.name).symbols;
```