# Cascading dropdown Edit is not working in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my object:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', symbol: 'H'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Hydrogen',  symbol: 'H1'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Helium',  symbol: 'He'}
];
```

which is displayed in datatable with *Edit* buttons, like so:

When I click *Edit* (for example I clicked *Hydrogen*) it should populate with
`name: 'Hydrogen', symbol: 'H'`.

But now I am getting the *Symbol List* dropdown empty.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-s4w99a?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

When I click the Add button, a pop up will come with two dropdowns: *Element List* and *Symbol List*. Based on the *Element* name Symbol List will come.

Now when I click the Edit button in datatable, that should populate that particular row in the popup. How can I do this?

**html**

```
<form  [formGroup]="addTaskForm"  (ngSubmit)="save()" >
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="name" placeholder="Element List"  (selectionChange)="elementSelectionChange($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let element of Elements" [value]="element.name">
        {{ element.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select  formControlName="symbol"  placeholder="Symbol List">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let element of selectedElementSymbol" [value]="element.symbol">
        {{ element.symbol }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div mat-dialog-actions>

    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit"  mat-button cdkFocusInitial>Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoule update `datasource` after each value added from the dialog, change your `save()` function like this:

```
save() {

    const data = this.data.originalform.dataSource.data;
    this.addTaskForm.value["id"]=data.length+1
    data.push(this.addTaskForm.value);
    this.data.originalform.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource<Element>(data); 
    console.log('working');
    console.log(this.addTaskForm.value);
  }
```

And to not forget to add a referer to the parent object `originalform` from this:

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { element: element,originalform:this }
    });
```

Hope this helps:)

**Edit:**

By call of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415350/cascading-dropdown-edit-is-not-working-in-angular#comment86002685_49417875), i updated the fiddle in [the following](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygd25k-dykwfu?file=app/table-pagination-example.ts) to fit the paginating in.

Adding paginator figures as following:

```
this.data.originalform.dataSource.paginator=this.data.originalform.paginator;
```

Comment: can you pls add demo

Comment: actually i am going to store this in datbase and retriving from there

Comment: actually, it is stored in datasource, not superficially present in the table.

Comment: hai when i add new record .it gets updated it datasource but count not get updated .check here  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygd25k?file=app/table-pagination-example.html

Comment: @itsme these are new features you tailed to your table :|, but i'll check out.

Comment: hai did u check that @Abra001

Comment: @itsme [yes i did](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygd25k-dykwfu?file=app/table-pagination-example.ts), i knew the answer before, just it took me until now to respond cuzi crashed my laptop accidentally.

Comment: @itsme make a new question

Answer (score 1):

The symbol list is initialized in the method `elementSelectionChange`, but
you are calling `elementSelectionChange($event)` only when the Element list selection changes.

```
 <mat-select formControlName="name" placeholder="Element List"  (selectionChange)="elementSelectionChange($event)">
```

One way you can do it is,

```
elementSelectionChange(event) {
    this.loadSymbols(event.value);
}

loadSymbols(name) {
    let value = this.Elements.find(e => e.name === name);
    this.selectedElementSymbol = this.Symbols.filter(e => e.id === value.id);
    console.log(this.selectedElementSymbol);
}
```

and then call `loadSymbols` in the `constructor`

```
constructor() {
   if (data.element) {
      this.name = data.element.name;
      this.symbol = data.element.symbol;
      this.loadSymbols(this.name);
    }
}
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-emq6vs)

Comment: hai when i add new record .it gets updated it datasource but count not get updated .check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygd25k?file=app/table-pagination-example.html